# Replacing string in multiline variable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I am trying to replace the string `{NUM}` in the following variable:

```
var table = '        <table class="full-width">\r\n' +
            '            <tbody>\r\n' +
            '            <tr>\r\n' +
            '                <td width="75%" class="border-right-dotted left-line-tab">\r\n' +
            '                    <span id="47_TOTAL-CHARGES_D_{NUM}" class="input-text"></span>\r\n' +
            '                </td>\r\n' +
            '                <td width="25%" class="center-text">\r\n' +
            '                    <span id="47_TOTAL-CHARGES_C_{NUM}" class="input-text"></span>\r\n' +
            '                </td>\r\n' +
            '            </tr>\r\n' +
            '            </tbody>\r\n' +
            '        </table>\r\n';
```

using the following jquery replace:
`table = table.replace("/{NUM}/gm", num);`

but it doesn't seem to work. Testing the regex in https://regex101.com/ seems to present that the regex is fine, but it still does not replace the text as expected.

[image]

Comment: You're looking for a string literal; you're not using a regex. Remove the quotes: `table.replace(/{NUM}/gm, num);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the double quotes:

```
table = table.replace(/{NUM}/gm, num);
```

A text within double quotes defines a string literal whilst you need a regular expression literal, which should be surrounded by slashes.

Comment: I feel so stupid! Thanks a bunch.